# Hide payment method if customer has more than one processing order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods

I'm trying to hide a payment method if a customer has more than one processing order, so I created a module call KgPayMethod and in this module, I added this line on events.xml

```
<event name="payment_method_is_active">
<observer name="custom_payment" instance="Ab\KgPayMethod\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
</event>
```

and my class like this :

```
<?php

namespace Ab\KgPayMethod\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if( $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == "banktransfer" )
        {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know how to get all customers orders and if he had one processing order, that hides the payment method only in this case.

Maybe use $observer->getEvent()->getQuote() ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on a good path. To understand what is and isn't available it is helpful to check how the event is dispatched and used.

You have already found the event itself `payment_method_is_active` - searching for it in the codebase will reveal how it is called:

```
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'payment_method_is_active',
            [
                'result' => $checkResult,
                'method_instance' => $this,
                'quote' => $quote
            ]
        );

        return $checkResult->getData('is_available');
```

The second parameter to the dispatch method shows what objects will be passed into the event. In this case you would have access to result, method_instance and the quote.

`$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` would not yield anything.

For your use case I suggest utilising `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()`. Then use the customer_id to run a search for any outstanding orders.

Comment: @RobertS. Kristof is given u the hint. `From quote object  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()` using you can get  customer id `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCustomerId()`.

Comment: Now, you have to get order collection of that customer using customer id

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Kristof at Fooman

First, you get **customer id**  of the current quote using `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCustomerId()`.

After that get Order COllection of that customer id.

## Observer code

```
<?php
namespace Ops\KgPayMethod\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder       
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if($quote === null){
            return $this;
        }
        // return immedia when Customer id does not exits on Guest Checkout
        if($quote->getCustomerId() === null  || $quote->getCustomerId() < 1 ){
            return $this;
        }
        $hasCustomerProcessingOrders = $this
                ->getOrderCollectionByCustomerId($quote->getCustomerId());
        if($hasCustomerProcessingOrders  && 
                $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == "banktransfer" )
        {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer List of Processing order 
     * 
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function getOrderCollectionByCustomerId($customerId)
    {
        $filterBuilder1 =[]; $filterBuilder2 = [];

        $filterBuilder1[] = $this->filterBuilder->setField('status')
                ->setConditionType('eq')
                ->setValue('processing')->create(); 

        $filterBuilder2[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('customer_id')
             ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue($customerId)->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilters($filterBuilder1)
                ->addFilters($filterBuilder2)
                ->setCurrentPage(1)
                ->setPageSize(1)
                ->create();
        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        if($orders->getTotalCount() >= 1 ){
            return  true;
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have this error now.. "Aucune entité avec OrderId = 2" in French...

Comment: I think the bug is on this line : $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

Comment: might be... i have checking this..

Comment: if i change the criteria, it change the order id

Comment: the condition was wrong, it is modified now.

Comment: yes, it works now thank you :)